# How can I speed up crc32 calculation?

Tags: c, crc32

I'm trying to write a crc32 implementation on linux that's as fast as possible, as an exercise in learning to optimise C. I've tried my best, but I haven't been able to find many good resources online. I'm not even sure if my buffer size is sensible; it was chosen by repeated experimentation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFFSIZE 1048567

const unsigned long int lookupbase = 0xEDB88320;
unsigned long int crctable[256] = {
0x00000000, 0x77073096, 0xEE0E612C, 0x990951BA,
/* LONG LIST OF PRECALCULTED VALUES */
0xB40BBE37, 0xC30C8EA1, 0x5A05DF1B, 0x2D02EF8D};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    register unsigned long int x;
    int i;
    register unsigned char *c, *endbuff;
    unsigned char buff[BUFFSIZE];
    register FILE *thisfile=NULL;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        thisfile = fopen(argv[i], "r");
        if (thisfile == NULL) {
            printf("Unable to open ");
        } else {
            x = 0xFFFFFFFF;
            c = &(buff[0]);
            endbuff = &(buff[fread(buff, (sizeof (unsigned char)), BUFFSIZE, thisfile)]);
            while (c != endbuff){
                while (c != endbuff){
                    x=(x>>8) ^ crctable[(x&0xFF)^*c];
                    c++;
                }
                c = &(buff[0]);
                endbuff = &(buff[fread(buff, (sizeof (unsigned char)), BUFFSIZE, thisfile)]);
            }
            fclose(thisfile);
            x = x ^ 0xFFFFFFFF;
            printf("%0.8X ", x);
        }
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or resources I can read through.

Comment: You're interleaving I/O with CRC calculations.  That's going to make it harder to measure small differences in the performance of the CRC code.

Comment: I'm not just interested in speeding up the CRC; if you have any suggestions for speeding up I/O on Linux I'd be glad to hear them.

Comment: It is important to know when *not* to optimize.  This is a very good example.  There's no point, the file I/O is many orders of magnitude slower than the crc calculation.  Speeding that up is going to require more expensive hardware, not code.

Comment: @HansPassant - It turns out that in this case, the I/O is actually the same order of magnitude as the CRC calculation - changing the line `x=(x>>8) ^ crctable[(x&0xFF)^*c];` to `x ^= *c` halves the runtime on my PC.

Comment: I love a miracle, skeptic on that one though.  Pay attention to Jim's comment.  For kicks, reboot your machine and try again.  Once.

Comment: You have to specify if you are trying to optimize your code for throughput (few large inputs), or invocation speed (many small inputs). If your code is decent, your throughput is limited by RAM or disk bandwidth (compare speed to e.g. xor-ing your input) and there's no point to optimize any further. For small inputs, program startup or function call overhead, namely stack and cache use are more important. In any case, remember to test with total input size much larger that L3 cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've asked for three values to be stored in registers, but standard x86 only has four general purpose registers: that's an awful lot of burden to place on the last remaining register, which is one reason why I expect `register` really only prevents you from ever using `&foo` to find the address of the variable. I don't think any modern compiler even uses it as a hint, these days. Feel free to remove all three uses and re-time your application.

Since you're reading in huge chunks of the file yourself, you might as well use `open(2)` and `read(2)` directly, and remove all the standard IO handling behind the scenes. Another common approach is to `open(2)` and `mmap(2)` the file into memory: let the OS page it in as pages are required. This may allow future pages to be *optimistically* read from disk while you're doing your computation: this is a common access pattern, and one the OS designers have attempted to optimize. (The *simple* mechanism of mapping the entire file at once does put an upper limit on the size of the files you can handle, probably about 2.5 gigabytes on 32-bit platforms and absolutely huge on 64-bit platforms. Mapping the file in chunks will allow you to handle arbitrary sized files even on 32-bit platforms, but at the cost of loops like you've got now for reading, but for mapping.)

As David Gelhar points out, you're using an odd-length buffer -- this might complicate the code path of reading the file into memory. If you want to stick with reading from files into buffers, I suggest using a multiple of `8192` (two pages of memory), as it won't have special cases until the last loop.

If you're really into eeking out of the last bit of speed and don't mind drastically increasing the size of your pre-computation table, you can look at the file in 16-bit chunks, rather than just 8-bit chunks. Frequently, accessing memory along 16-bit alignment is faster than along 8-bit alignment, and you'd cut the number of iterations through your loop in half, which usually gives a huge speed boost. The downside, of course, is increased memory pressure (65k entries, each of 8 bytes, rather than just 256 entries each of 4 bytes), and the much larger table is much less likely to fit entirely in the CPU cache.

And the last optimization idea that crosses my mind is to `fork(2)` into 2, 3, or 4 processes (or use threading), each of which can compute the crc32 of a *portion* of the file, and then combine the end results after all processes have completed. crc32 may not be computationally intensive enough to actually benefit from trying to use multiple cores out of SMP or multicore computers, and figuring out how to combine partial computations of crc32 may not be feasible -- I haven't looked into it myself :) -- but it might repay the effort, and learning how to write multi-process or multi-threaded software is well worth the effort regardless.

Comment: So it turns out that mmaping ~500MB files into memory and then looping through them takes ages - about 3 times as long as what I had before. I was looping through the mmap one byte at a time; I'm not sure if Linux interpereted this as me wanting the file to be loaded into memory byte by byte...

Switching to `open` and `read` provided no noticable change in runtime; however, I am testing the case of a few large files - maybe with many small files it will make a difference.

Doubling the chunk size is an interesting idea; I'll have a proper look at it tomorrow.

Thanks

Comment: The BUFSIZE looks like 2**20 with the last two digits accidentially swapped.  :D

Answer (score 4):

On Linux? Forget about the `register` keyword, that's just a *suggestion* to the compiler and, from my experience with `gcc`, it's a waste of space. `gcc` is *more* than capable of figuring that out for itself.

I would just make sure you're compiling with the insane optimisation level, `-O3`, and check that. I've seen `gcc` produce code at that level which took me hours to understand, so sneaky that it was.

And, on the buffer size, make it as large as you possibly can. Even with buffering, the cost of calling `fread` is still a cost, so the less you do it, the better. You would see a huge improvement if you increased the buffer size from 1K to 1M, not so much if you up it from 1M to 2M, but even a small amount of increased performance is an increase. And, 2M isn't the upper bound of what you can use, I'd set it to one or more *gigabytes* if possible.

You may then want to put it at file level (rather than inside `main`). At some point, the stack won't be able to hold it.

As with most optimisations, you can usually trade space for time. Keep in mind that, for small files (less than 1M), you won't see any improvement since there is still only one read no matter how big you make the buffer. You may even find a slight slowdown if the loading of the process has to take more time to set up memory.

But, since this would only be for small files (where the performance isn't a problem anyway), it shouldn't really matter. Large files, where the performance *is* an issue, should hopefully find an improvement.

And I know I don't need to tell *you* this (since you indicate you are doing it), but I will mention it anyway for those who don't know: *Measure, don't guess!* The ground is littered with the corpses of those who optimised with guesswork :-)

Comment: Initially I thought `register` wouldn't do anything, but adding it in did give me a speedup when I experimented with `time` -- although I'm not sure if that was before I started compiling with an explicit -O3 flag or not.
I arrived at the buffer size by increasing it until `time` stopped showing any speed increase, but you're right; making the number bigger can't really hurt.

Answer (score 3):

You are not going to be able to speed up the actual arithmetic of the CRC calculation, so the areas you can look at are the overhead of (a) reading the file, and (b) looping.

You're using a pretty large buffer size, which is good (but why is it an odd number?). Using a read(2) system call (assuming you're on a unix-like system) instead of the fread(3) standard library function may save you one `copy` operation (copying the data from fread's internal buffer into your bufffer).

For the loop overhead, look into [loop unrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding).

---

Your code also has some redundancies that you might want to eliminate.

- `sizeof (unsigned char)` is 1 (by definition in C); no need to explicitly compute it
- `c = &(buff[0])` is exactly equivalent to `c = buff`

Neither of these changes will improve the performance of the code (assuming a decent compiler), but they will make it clearer and more in accordance with usual C style.

Comment: The reason the buffer size is an odd number is because I accidentally typed 1048567 instead of 1048576, which is 2^20. No idea how that slipped through - nice spot.

Comment: sizeof (unsigned char) is not computed, it is set at compile time, same for c=buff vs c=&(buff[0]).